# check if a user exists in Intercom

Tags: php, symfony, intercom

I want to delete a user from my database and from intercom in the same time
but I want to check if this user exists in intercom or not:

```
public function deleteUserAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $intercom = IntercomBasicAuthClient::factory(array(
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
        'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));   
    $user = $doctrine->getRepository('ZaidUserBundle:User')->find($id);

    if($user) {
        //delete user from intercom
        //I want some condition here 
        $intercom->deleteUser(array("email" => $user->getEmail()));
        //delete user from database
        $em->remove($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new Response(200);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$intercom->getUser(array("email" => $user->getEmail()));`?

Comment: thanks COil your code is correcte but if user who has this email dont existe in intercom i have error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Matteo 
this solution works for me

```
public function deleteUserAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $intercom = IntercomBasicAuthClient::factory(array(
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
        'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));   
    $user = $doctrine->getRepository('ZaidUserBundle:User')->find($id);
    $existe = 1;
    if($user) {
        //delete user from intercom
        //I want some condition here 
         try{
        $intercom->deleteUser(array("email" => $user->getEmail()));

        } catch (\Intercom\Exception\IntercomException $e) {
                $existe = 0;
            }
        //delete user from database
if($existe==1){
        $em->remove($user);
        $em->flush();
}
    }

    return new Response(200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [doc here](https://github.com/atlir/intercom-php#users), you should retrieve an user by email simply as:

```
// Find user by email
$intercom->getUser(array("email" => "bob@example.com"));
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for your answer.but if user is existe your code its ok but if this user who has this email is not existe in intercom i have error

var_dump($intercom->getUser(array("email" => "bob@example.com")));

Comment: hi @AitFrihaZaid which kind of error? Is a specific exception you can catch? Can you add this info in your question?

Comment: hi @Matteo

 [2017-04-06 15:19:07] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Intercom\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException: "Client error response [status code] 404 [reason phrase] Not Found [url] https://api.intercom.io/users/?email=bob%40example.com"

i know already that this email dont existe in the intercom but i want to have NULL if note existe and not a error 
thanks you Matteo

Comment: if you search for an existing one? which result you have?

Comment: var_dump($intercom->getUser(array("email" => $user->getEmail())));die();
=>
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)[802]
  protected 'structure' => null
  protected 'data' => 
    array (size=30)
      'type' => string 'user' (length=4)
      'id' => string '57ed02ff9a812be64f3dc4ae' (length=24)
      'user_id' => string '31' (length=2)
      'anonymous' => boolean false
      'email' => string 'test@leegggle.com' (length=17)